# How can i create this format of date time directory but with my format?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The test i did is:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd dd.MM.yyyy");
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm tt");
string format = "{0} from {1} At {2}";
string cp = string.Format(format, "", date, time);
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\\temp\\" + cp);
```

The result in the variable cp is: from Fri 20.01.2017 At 09.27 AM
And there is no problem to create this directory.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countriesNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                string pathDateTime = urls[0].Substring(48, 12);
                string pathDateTimeLast = urls[urls.Count - 1].Substring(48, 12);
                var d = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var e = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTimeLast, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string country = countriesNames[i].Substring(15);
                string f = "{0} from {1} At {2} until {3}";
                string countryPath = countriesMainPath + "\\" + country + "\\" + string.Format(f, "", d,e);
                if (!Directory.Exists(countryPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(countryPath);
                }
                countryPaths.Add(countryPath);
            }
```

The way i did it with the 'f' variable is not right and not working fine give me exception.

In my code in the variable 'd' there is 20/01/2017 05:15:00 
And in variable 'e' 20/01/2017 07:30:00

But i can't create this directories.
So i want to format my date and time after extracting them to be like the format in the first example: from Fri 20.01.2017 At 09.27 AM but with my date and time.

For example my directory should be something like:

from Fri 20.1.2017 At 05:15 AM Until 20.1.2017 At 07:30 AM
Then to create this directory: "from Fri 20.1.2017 At 05:15 AM Until 20.1.2017 At 07:30 AM"

The question is how do i format my dates and times after parsed to this format ?

Comment: I suggest you clean up the question and clearly explain how the path should look like and what was the problem. This code creates a *lot* of confusion, especially since you mix up calls to `String.Format` *and* concatenate strings. Why don't you just use one path format and pass all components as parameters?

Comment: Daniel, I just got a call from the future you. He asked me to tell you to stop using variable names like `d` and `f` and start writing meaningful variable names.

Comment: suggest using `DateTime.UtcNow`. "Bad things" will happen at the end of DST

Comment: @DanielDeJunior *why* are you using the time in the path? What are you trying to store? Why not use eg a logging library and let it generate the appropriate folders? Or use a date-only path? How many files do you expect to store in each folder and what do they contain? Why not just append to a single log or event file for example?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have 40 directories of countries. In each country every 15 minutes i'm downloading satellite images of it's on region/country and i want to store this images and let the user to possible way to watch the images later in the future. So i want to let the user to know what range of date and time the images were downloaded. The range on the site is every 15 minutes new updated images and each time it's 10 images. Each image is updated every 15 minutes. The same time and date is for each country but not same images.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so each time if we take for example turkey as country. In the next 15 minutes for example the site will generate new 10 images. The first image will be at 17:00 the last image 19:45 the next time it will be from 19:45 ....If 'im not mistaken. I will check now on the site in the next update to see if it's updating only the last image every 15 minutes and the push the rest one place(time) or updating all the 10 images.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here is a link for example for one country Spain. You can see on the bottom the times. Now it's from 04:45 to 07:00 let's wait for the next update in few minutes. http://en.sat24.com/en/sp/infraPolair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a path by formatting dates using your current locale's default (long) format. In most countries the date separator is `/` and the time separator is always `:`. This results in invalid paths.

It's a bit hard to understand what format you want to use, since you mix calls to String.Format *and* concatenate the results. It seems that the original path should be:

```
var cp=String.Format(@"c:\temp\From {0:ddd dd.MM.yyyy} At {0:HH.mm tt}",DateTime.Now);
```

or

```
var root="c:\temp\";
var partialPath = String.Format("From {0:ddd dd.MM.yyyy} At {0:HH.mm tt}",DateTime.Now)
var cp=Path.Combine(root,partialPath);
```

You don't need to format each component separately. If you check the documentation of [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that you can use a composite format string for each placeholder.

The country path seems to be

```
var partialPath = String.Format(@"{0}\from {1:ddd dd.MM.yyyy} At {1:HH.mm tt} until {2:HH.mm tt}",
                                country,d,e);
var countryPath =Path.Combine(countriesMainPath,partialPath);
```

That said, I wouldn't use that date format. The resulting folder names can't be sorted in a meaningful way making it difficult for users to find folders by date. I'd use the `yyyy-MM-dd` format, or `yyyy-MM-dd ddd` if the name of the day is really necessary.

Comment: suggest using `DateTime.UtcNow`. "Bad things" will happen at the end of DST

Comment: @AndyPook correct, although that should be a comment to the OP. I'd never use time-based paths. In fact, this smells like a logging scenario. I'd use a logging library like NLog, log4net, Serilog etc, in this case and let them deal with rolling files.